# Why the operation on accumulator doesn't work without collect()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning Spark and following a tutorial. In an exercise I am trying to do some analysis on a data set. This data set has data in each line like:

```
userid | age | gender | ...
```

I have the following piece of code:

```
....

under_age = sc.accumulator(0)
over_age = sc.accumulator(0)


def count_outliers(data):
    global under_age, over_age
    if data[1] == '0-10':
        under_age += 1
    if data[1] == '80+':
        over_age += 1
    return data


data_set.map(count_outliers).collect()
print('Kids: {}, Seniors: {}'.format(under_age, over_age))
```

I found that I must use the method ".collect()" to make this code work. That is, without calling this method, the code won't count the two accumulators. But in my understanding ".collect()" is used to get the whole dataset to the memory. Why it is necessary here? Is it sth related to lazy evaluation thing? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is due to lazy evaluation.

Spark doesn't calculate anything until you execute an [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) such as `collect`, and the accumulators are only updated as a side-effect of that calculation.

[Transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations) such as `map` define what work needs to be done, but it's only executed once an action is triggered to "pull" the data through the transformations.

This is described in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators):

> Accumulators do not change the lazy evaluation model of Spark. If they are being updated within an operation on an RDD, their value is only updated once that RDD is computed as part of an action. Consequently, accumulator updates are not guaranteed to be executed when made within a lazy transformation like map().

It's also important to note that:

> In transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed.

so your accumulators will not necessarily give correct answers; they may overstate the totals.